# What is the distribution of a q-matrix in q learning?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning, artificial-intelligence, q-learning

Quick question, what is the distribution of a q-matrix in standard q learning? As a q-matrix, lets assume a 2x2 matrix with states 1 and 2, and actions A and B. And lets further assume that In state 1, the values in the matrix are 15 and 20 for actions A and B respectively, and in state 2, the values in the matrix are 40 and 35 for actions A and B respectively. This policy tells the agent to definitely take action B in state 1 and action A in state 2. What sort of distribution is this? It tells us that if in state 1, do action B with Probability 1 and action A with probability 0, and vice versa for state 2. But is this a distribution because there is no uncertainty. My reading is currently leading me to believe that it is a mixture model of discrete uniform distributions.

Furthermore, over time the agent will be learning and therefore the values in the Q-matrix change. Hence, is the q-matrix even a distribution or should it more rightly be classified as a belief?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q function is an estimate of discounted reward for given state and action. Specifically, of the expected value of that reward. There's no direct reason to read Q matrix as a distribution.

On the other hand, there's a traditional approach for randomized action selection that addresses the exploration-exploitation problem. It's name is softmax.

You may benefit from googling on:

- Bayesian Q Learning: [here](https://ocs.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/1998/AAAI98-108.pdf)
- Lazy fully probabilistic design: [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-12436-0_16)